# Can't capture chef error to a file

Tags: chef

If I run the following:

```
chef-client --force-formatter --logfile STDOUT 2>&1
```

And then control-c it mid-run (or encounter any sort of error) I see this nice error message:

```
[2014-09-12T00:00:30-04:00] FATAL: SIGINT received, stopping

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/users/recipes/fen.rb
================================================================================


SystemExit
----------
exit


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/users/recipes/default.rb:11:in ``'
  /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/users/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'
  /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/users/recipes/fen.rb:15:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/cache/chef/cookbooks/users/recipes/default.rb:

etc...

[2014-09-12T00:00:30-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-09-12T00:00:30-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-09-12T00:00:30-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/cache/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
```

But if I do the following:

```
chef-client --force-formatter --logfile STDOUT 2>&1 | tee /tmp/chef.log
```

And then control-c, I see all the log messages I was seeing before, with the exception of that nice fatal message telling me what was happening. The file I'm piping too also doesn't show the fatal message.

So apparently chef-client is detecting whether or not it's piping to an actual file descriptor, and suppressing output if it is. Does anyone know of a way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Uhm ... why not `--logfile /tmp/chef.log`?

Comment: That only logs the fact that there was a fatal to the file, it doesn't log the actual stacktrace I showed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a neat hack

```
script -c chef-client /tmp/chef.log
```

Does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Chef outputs the error to STDERR instead of STDOUT despite specifying STDOUT as logfile. The following command should work:

```
chef-client --force-formatter --logfile STDOUT 2>&1 | tee /tmp/chef.log
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the output on either stdout or stderr when piping, it simply isn't output.

Answer (score 0):

A better option than the 2 other answers appears to be:

```
chef-client -o recipe_name --format doc --no-color | tee output.log
```

The `doc` format prints the progress of the chef-client run using full strings that display a summary of updates as they occur.